# Git clone from remote repo hangs after Compressing Objects 100% done

Tags: git, git-clone, openvpn

I work in Windows 7, 64-bit.

I want to check out source code from a private git repo which I am connected to by OpenVPN.

I connected to a private server via OpenVPN for Windows. The connection is established and works fine, I can `ping` the server and connect via SSH to it.

Next, I want to clone the git repository via

```
 git clone http://username:pw@url/folder
```

Bash shows immediately

```
Cloning into "projektname"
remote: Counting Objects: 6772, done
remote: Compressing Objects: 100% (6389/6389),done
_
```

and then hangs, no error, no clue what happens, I can cut the VPN connection to get a response from git or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but nothing else.

git created a folder `projektname` but it is empty except for the `.git` folder.

I looked through forum posts for several hours, but haven't found a similar post with the same problem. I tried to get more information on git with

```
 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone ....
```

but didn't find anything suspicious. I am thankful for any ideas about what else I can try or where I have to look into. I tried several different git clients (cygwin, Tortoise, git bash, git gui).

Comment: If you leave it running, does it eventually time out?

Comment: no timeout within 2 hours so far

Comment: how big is your repository?

Comment: unfortunatly I don´t know, but there shouldn´t be any big files, it only consists of javascript files for a web app

Comment: As .git is present, can you do `git pull`, or `git branch -a` and if so, does it give anything?

Comment: git pull  results in the same screen as described in my post, git branch -a doesn´t do anything

Comment: maybe a bug in your version of git ?

Comment: I tried it on different laptops, with differnet git clients

Comment: I found the solution... something with my router setup is wrong. I can check out from another network. I have no clue what could be wrong with my router , every othern VPN connections just works fine

Comment: Try using `git fetch`.  E.g. `mkdir foo; cd foo; git init; git remote add origin <url>; git fetch origin; git checkout master`

Comment: @baumi1543 Thank you. I had the same problem, I could connect to VPN being able to acces DB and other private pages, but I was not able to use git properly. I connected to VPN using other network and now git works fine too.

Comment: I had the same issue where compressing process was abnormally long. I had to wait for ~5 mins to successfully clone the repo. It turned out it was because there are two relatively large files in my repo, each ~ 40MB.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer (So users will know how to resolve it if they need to).
The answer was posted by the owner in one of the above comments.

> I found the solution... something with my router setup is wrong.
>   I can check out from another network.
>   I have no clue what could be wrong with my router , every other VPN connections just works fine.

So the problem was with the router and has nothing to do with git.